# Python Pandas create Date Time index from date

Tags: python, date, pandas, datetime

I have the following python pandas dataframe df:

```
    DATES       Sales
0   1/6/2013    5676
1   1/8/2014    45746
2   1/10/2015   42658
3   1/14/2015   890790
4   1/16/2016   5764
5   1/20/2014   7898
```

I need to change DATES to a Date Time Index, so that i can resample it.

But when I do this

```
pd.to_datetime(df,infer_datetime_format=True)
```

I get the following error:
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

Comment: You need to specify the column that your dates appear in: `pd.to_datetime(df['DATES'])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should explicitly define the format

```
pd.to_datetime(df['DATES'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

and not let Pandas guess

*[to_datetime() documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)*

To set a datetime as an index

```
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DATES']))
```

---

Works for non-padded month and day:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'1/6/2013' : 5676}
df = pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns=['DATES', 'Sales'])
df['DATES'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATES'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

> > 0   2013-01-06

Comment: thank you, when I use pd.to_datetime(df['DATES'],format='%m/%d/%Y'), it does not update the dates in the dataframe, but creates a series when I do df = pd.to_datetime(df['DATES'],format='%m/%d/%Y'); the sales column disappears

Comment: You have to assign a single column `df['DATES']` instead of the entire dataframe `df`. See my updated code snippet